# Bold text distorted with iText printed

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iText with a Visual Studio 2019 project (c#). I show PDF generated in DocumentViewer control and I have a button to save PDF File. This PDF is composed by several font styles.

I can print PDF file in two ways:

- Print DocumentViewer control
- Print PDF saved

If I print PDF from DocumentViewer bold text is distorted and doubled when the line is long.
If I print PDF from PDF file it shows fine.

Is there any code in iText to correct that distortion?

Comment: How is this related with iText? iText does not render, let alone print. (Except you mean iText 7 with the pdfRender add-on, that is.)

Comment: Then, is is a printer issue?

Comment: It may also be a broken pdf. As you neither share any code nor an example pdf to analyze, no one knows.